# Parsing Json from URL in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, gson

I am trying to parse some JSON. I have lately been attempting to use **GSON** to do so in android studio. However, I can't seem to obtain a connection or do anything with the data. The data I would be looking at, if I could ever obtain it from the site would look something like this:

```
{"item":{"icon":"address_here",
id=820","id":820,"type":"Default",
"typeIcon":"catagory","name":"Name of Object",
"description":"This is an annoying issue to get stuck on"}}
```

I have been using async, but to no avail. Perhaps a new way to look at this would be good.

Here's my current code:

```
    public class JavaParser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
public String getInternetData() throws Exception {
    String sURL = "someurl.com"; //just a string

    // Connect to the URL using java's native library

    try {
        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Log.d("Debug:", "Made partial connection");
        try {
            request.connect();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Debug:", "Made connection");
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    return "FAILURE";
}
private String response = null;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
    try {
        response = new JavaParser().getInternetData();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    Log.d("Error",e.getMessage()
    );
    }
    return response;
}
```

}

In my main class:

```
    String response = new JavaParser().execute("URL").get();        //eventually I hope to pass the url here to be more dynamic
        //Convert to a JSON object to print data
        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser(); //from gson
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent())); //Convert the input stream to a json element
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject(); //May be an array, may be an object.

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Wrapper response = gson.fromJson(rootobj, Wrapper.class);


        Log.d("Out: ",rootobj.get("item\name").getAsString()); //just grab the name info
```

And my wrapper looks like so:

```
    public class Wrapper   {

@SerializedName("name")
public String item_name;

@SerializedName("icon")
public String iconURL;

@SerializedName("description")
public  String item_description;

//more to be added if it works
```

}

The program only ever makes partial connection. I cannot seem to get the line
        request.connect();
to function whatsoever.

Comment: Show us what you tried until now, so we can help you...

Comment: Do you get to your `catch` block? If so, what is the stacktrace? If not, what *does* happen? Have you declared `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the permission was in the wrong part of the manifest. It needs to be near the top, I put it as such

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.yargonauts.burk.app">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```